# Leaking pipes somewhere but don't know where

Tags: plumbing-fixture, leaking

I had frozen pipes during the recent winter storm in TX. Now the weather warms up and water came back. My Flume device detecting water leakage about 2 gallons per hour for the last 24 hours.  No leaking signs inside the house or attic. Suspect it's the underground pipe but how do I pinpoint where?  Called the insurance company and they have not replied back. Help please

Comment: Have you turned off your main valve (the first one after the water meter)? If that's off and the meter still shows flow, then the leak is in the underground pipe. If no flow with that off, the leak is inside your plumbing and you'll need to start hunting.

Comment: Hint: 48 gallons that you still can't see means it's not upstairs ;)

Comment: turn off mains. wait one hour. open faucet. If nothing comes out, you have a leak. If a little comes out then stops, you're probably fine.

Comment: 2 gallons an hour is not a lot there could be a “pinhole” leak in a pipe in the wall. If you can not hear water flow by listening method look under the home. A few years back my daughters home sprang a leak in a wall it was small but after a week the small spray cut through the drywall she did not have a monitor, did not notice anything until the spray cut through. I was surprised it took so long. I had to cut a chunk of Sheetrock out but it needed to dry out anyway sweated in a new piece of copper and things were fine. After looking at those flume devices you pay for the water from that point

Answer (score 0):

I use a broom stick or dowel place it on the ground then my ear to the dowel.

Yes a 3 or 4’ dowel works better than one you have to kneel down for.

Ipoh are turning the stick into a stethoscope. I listen if I can here water I move on until I can no longer hear the water movement.

I take extra time on sidewalks or driveways as these are places pipe likes to break.
In some cases you can hear the flowing water pickup rocks and hit the concrete.

The break can also be under the house. By using this method I have found broken pipes and even located drain pipes under slabs when I did not know where they went having someone tap on the pipe with a wrench or hammer may help you to find it in some cases if it turns and you loose the sound.

If you find a spot the water noise stops turn the water on in the house if you now hear it the break is usually 1-2’ closer to the main, I have had really good luck using a broomstick or even a 1/4” wood dowel I think anything solid would also work to transmit the vibrations.